# Plotting binary response variable against continuous explanatory variable

Tags: r

When i try to plot a binary response variable (Goose field Y or N) against a continuous response variable (field size) using:

```
plot(formula=main$GOOSE_FIELD~main$M2)
```

it produces a bar plot instead of a rug plot with data points lined up against Y or N on y axis.
How can I produce the rug plot format?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: When asking for help you should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. What exactly do you mean by "rug" plot.

Comment: its sometimes more standard to plot the points and add a smoother eg. `plot(am ~ mpg , data=mtcars) ; with(loess(am~mpg, data=mtcars, span=1),      lines(fitted[order(x)] ~ x[order(x)]))`

Comment: And possibly add some jitter to the suggestion by @user2957945 to prevent overplotting